# Controller/Actions not appearing on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just created a new controller and a couple actions, but when I try to look at them on localhost I get the error: `No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"user"}`

the controller looks like this:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def register
    @title = 'Register'
  end
end
```

shouldn't I just be able to go http://localhost:3000/user/register and have something appear after creating a new controller?

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE** - Added Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'user/index'

  get 'user/register'

  get 'site/index'

  get 'site/about'

  get 'site/help'

      root 'site#index'
end
```

Comment: Typically you would call it UsersController. What does 'rake routes' tell you? Can you show us your routes.rb file?

Comment: How, exactly, did you create a new controller? Did you create the file manually? Did you use rails g controller? Did you use rails g scaffold User?

Comment: I created the controller by: rails generate controller

Answer (score 1):

For the action to be accessible from the browser you will need to create routes to that endpoint. [Here is a guide regarding routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: when you say create routes to that endpoint do you mean `get 'user/index'` in the routes.rb?